# uri.path removes disk name on Windows

Tags: windows, groovy, uri, filepath

Why removes Uri.path the disk name on Windows.

Here is an example:

```
def path = 'C:/Users/test/project/project.jar'
def f = new URI(path).path
```

output: f = '/Users/test/project/project.jar'

How can i avoid this?

Comment: `path = 'file:/D:/Users/test/project/project.jar'; println new URI(path).path` will give you `/D:/...`.  can windows/java handle this?